# filter a new customfield Phreeze

Tags: search, filter, phreeze

I am using [Phreeze](http://phreeze.com) to create an application.
Everything goes right but when I want to filter in a template a custom field (tagtypeName) it doesn't do it.

I have the model in model.js:

```
model.TagModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: 'api/tag',
    idAttribute: 'id',
    id: '',
    name: '',
    type: '',
    TagtypeName: '',
    baja: '',
    defaults: {
        'id': null,
        'name': '',
        'type': '',
        'baja': ''
    }
});
```

My criteria is TagCriteria.php:

```
public function GetFieldFromProp($propname)
    {
        switch($propname)
        {
            case 'TagtypeName':
                return 'tagtype.id';
            case 'Id':
                return 'tag.id';    
            case 'Name':
                return 'tag.name';
            case 'Type':
                return 'tag.type';
            case 'Baja':
                return 'tag.baja';  
            default:
                return parent::GetFieldFromProp($propname);
                //throw new Exception('Unable to locate the database column for the property: ' . $propname);
        }
    }
```

My reporter is:
public $Id;
    public $Name;
    public $Type;
    public $Baja;
    public $TagtypeName;

```
/*
* GetCustomQuery returns a fully formed SQL statement.  The result columns
* must match with the properties of this reporter object.
*
* @see Reporter::GetCustomQuery
* @param Criteria $criteria
* @return string SQL statement
*/
static function GetCustomQuery($criteria)
{
    $sql = "select
        `tagtype`.`name` as TagtypeName
        ,`tag`.`id` as Id
        ,`tag`.`name` as Name
        ,`tag`.`type` as Type
        ,`tag`.`baja` as Baja
    from `tag`
    inner join `tagtype` on `tagtype`.`id`=`tag`.`type`";

    // the criteria can be used or you can write your own custom logic.
    // be sure to escape any user input with $criteria->Escape()
    $sql .= $criteria->GetWhere();
    $sql .= $criteria->GetOrder();

    return $sql;
}
```

the view has:

```
        <script type="text/template" id="tagCollectionTemplate">
            <table class="collection table table-bordered table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th id="header_Id">Id<% if (page.orderBy == 'Id') { %> <i class='icon-arrow-<%= page.orderDesc ? 'up' : 'down' %>' /><% } %></th>
                    <th id="header_Name">Name<% if (page.orderBy == 'Name') { %> <i class='icon-arrow-<%= page.orderDesc ? 'up' : 'down' %>' /><% } %></th>
                    <!--<th id="header_Type">Type<% if (page.orderBy == 'Type') { %> <i class='icon-arrow-<%= page.orderDesc ? 'up' : 'down' %>' /><% } %></th>-->
                    <th id="header_Type">Type<% if (page.orderBy == 'TagtypeName') { %> <i class='icon-arrow-<%= page.orderDesc ? 'up' : 'down' %>' /><% } %></th>
                    <th id="header_Baja">Baja<% if (page.orderBy == 'Baja') { %> <i class='icon-arrow-<%= page.orderDesc ? 'up' : 'down' %>' /><% } %></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <% items.each(function(item) { %>
                <tr id="<%= _.escape(item.get('id')) %>">
                    <td><%= _.escape(item.get('id') || '') %></td>
                    <td><%= _.escape(item.get('name') || '') %></td>
                    <!--<td><%= _.escape(item.get('type') || '') %></td>-->
                    <td><%= _.escape(item.get('tagtypeName') || '') %></td>
                    <td><%= _.escape(item.get('baja') || '') %></td>
                </tr>
            <% }); %>
            </tbody>
            </table>

            <%=  view.getPaginationHtml(page) %>
        </script>
```

and in my controller I've changed the Tag to my reporter:

```
$tags = $this->Phreezer->Query('TagReporter',$criteria)->GetDataPage($page, $pagesize);
```

So when I go to the page I see the table instead of with the type id, it has the name of the type from my custome query as needed
[image]

but when I filter, no data is found with the new custom field:
[image]

Does anyone know how to handle this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I had to change the reporter count and put the inner joins:

```
static function GetCustomCountQuery($criteria)
    {
        $sql = "select count(1) as counter from `tag`
        inner join `tagtype` on `tagtype`.`id`=`tag`.`type`";

        // the criteria can be used or you can write your own custom logic.
        // be sure to escape any user input with $criteria->Escape()
        $sql .= $criteria->GetWhere();

        return $sql;
    }
```

Doing this it works OK for me!